# running simpy in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, simpy

I have created a simulation with simpy in python, there are several processes I have implemented within this simulation.

For training an on-policy DRL algorithm I need several environments in parallel.
at first I was thinking if several `simpy.Environmet()` are defined then we run each one in a `for` loop then they will be run in parallel, but after working some time on the code I found out one `Environment` postpones another until is ran completely.
now I am looking for a way for running identical `simpy.Environment` with its processes in parallel.

Comment: Each environment runs a infinite loop until runtime is reached.  You will need to look at python multiprocessing (not multithreading) to do this.  However commutation between processes is very difficult.

Why do you need to do it this way?  Can't you have a master process for each environment?

Comment: @Michael Dear Michael I have explored multiprocessing module, I know that I can use this module , but as you may know I have no idea how to share events between processes as they are highly dependent. To answer your question on why I have to do it in this way is that I have a huge code and if I want to change it to a single master kind then I have to give my code a huge edit, I was wondering if there is any way to prevent doing that, and of course this will speed up my simulation too.

Comment: multiprocessing will be very hard.  You will not have a common clock so keeping the your processes in sync will be a nightmare.  when you share data you are really sharing copies.  So if you share a event, any changes you make to that event will not be passes to the original process.  A lot of you speed gains you would gain from using multiple processors you would lose when a process has to wait on another process to catch up to the same clock time.